# Composer Require: Could not find package

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to use this: https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php

so I run: `composer require digitaldonkey/ethereum-php` but I get:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package digitaldonkey/ethereum-php at any version for
>   your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your
>   minimum-stability

So I imagine I need to specify some other branch but what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open your `composer.json` if that package has no stable version then you have to change your `minimum-stability` to `dev`.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability

Comment: my minimum-stability is set to dev already and I still get the same error, any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

The reason behind this error is your git repo does not contain any tags.

Add tags like

```
git tag -a 1.0.0
git push --tags
```

Now you can use

```
composer require digitaldonkey/ethereum-php
```

**Explanation**
If we see composer.json, you will find require tag which contains packages along with their versions. e.g.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "afrazahmad/clear-cached-data": "^1.0"
},
```

So versions or tags are important.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Why we need to add tags

Comment: Please read the error that he mentioned in the question. This answer is only related to that problem.

Comment: For those wondering why their repository tag is not working, be sure the tag follows the [v]?(major).(minor).(revision) format.

Comment: Save my day, Thanks dude

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding to a different folder other than the project, you get the same error. delete your previous installation and try cd project_name.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another case here where this error might occur.

When you have a **private repository** which provides a shared library, you will need to add the repository for it like so:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://YOURHANDLE.gitlab.io/composer"
        }
    ]
```

More on the topic here: https://composer.github.io/satis/using

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue on job.

in my case,error was occured because of lack the `repositories` block